# new column with condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements, numeric

I have a column `stday2` which has range of numbers as study days. I want to create four column from it.

```
1st col      <10

2nd col     >= 10 $ <=50)

3rd col      >50 $ <=80

4th col.      >80
```

How can I put condition for 2nd and third col

Comment: Can you show a small example.  I think you need either `ifelse` or  just a simple logical expression

Comment: Sounds like a job for `ifelse(x >= 10 && x <= 50, <a>, <b>)`, but won't know for sure until you post a representative data sample

Comment: id stday age  stday2            
1  1    20  66      9      
2  2    20  80     11    
3  3    20  27     10    
4  4    20  52     13    
5  5    20  84     12  
6  6    20  30     11

Comment: Can you please update your post with `edit`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something similar to this. Please next time use `dput()` to share your data. I have created some dummy data based on some variables shared in comments. You can combine `dplyr` and `tidyr` functions with conditionals using `ifelse()` to create initially the group, after that you can reshape the data to wide in order to get the expected columns. The ones in each column show which id belongs to certain group based on `stday2` while zeroes mean that the value is not present. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
set.seed(123)
#Data
df <- data.frame(id=c(1:20),
                 stday=rnorm(20,0,1),
                 age=round(runif(20,0,100),0),
                 stday2=round(runif(20,0,100)))
#Code
newdf <- df %>% mutate(Var=ifelse(stday2<10,'col1',
                         ifelse(stday2>=10 & stday2<=50,'col2',
                                ifelse(stday2>50 & stday2<=80,'col3','col4')))) %>%
  mutate(Val=1,Var=factor(Var,levels = c('col1','col2',
                                         'col3','col4'),ordered = T)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Var,values_from=Val,values_fill = 0,names_sort = T)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 8
      id   stday   age stday2  col1  col2  col3  col4
   <int>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 -0.560     14     67     0     0     1     0
 2     2 -0.230     41      9     1     0     0     0
 3     3  1.56      41     38     0     1     0     0
 4     4  0.0705    37     27     0     1     0     0
 5     5  0.129     15     81     0     0     0     1
 6     6  1.72      14     45     0     1     0     0
 7     7  0.461     23     81     0     0     0     1
 8     8 -1.27      47     81     0     0     0     1
 9     9 -0.687     27     79     0     0     1     0
10    10 -0.446     86     44     0     1     0     0
11    11  1.22       5     75     0     0     1     0
12    12  0.360     44     63     0     0     1     0
13    13  0.401     80     71     0     0     1     0
14    14  0.111     12      0     1     0     0     0
15    15 -0.556     56     48     0     1     0     0
16    16  1.79      21     22     0     1     0     0
17    17  0.498     13     38     0     1     0     0
18    18 -1.97      75     61     0     0     1     0
19    19  0.701     90     35     0     1     0     0
20    20 -0.473     37     11     0     1     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base solution that that uses `findInterval` to put the data into intervals that are used to `reshape` the data. The border conditions might need to be checked, but since the data appears to be whole numbers then 50 could be change to 49 if needed.

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:6, stday = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L
     ), age = c(66L, 80L, 27L, 52L, 84L, 30L), stday2 = c(9L, 11L, 
     10L, 13L, 12L, 11L), col = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2)), row.names = c("1", 
     "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")

df1$col <- findInterval(df1$stday2, c(10, 50, 80), left.open = TRUE) + 1

reshape(df1, idvar = c('id', 'stday', 'age'), timevar = 'col', direction = 'wide')

  id stday age stday2.1 stday2.2
1  1    20  66        9       NA
2  2    20  80       NA       11
3  3    20  27       10       NA
4  4    20  52       NA       13
5  5    20  84       NA       12
6  6    20  30       NA       11
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `reshape` (thanks to the data frame from [@Duck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64359074/12158757))

```
reshape(
  transform(df,
    grp = findInterval(stday2, c(10, 50, 80)) + 1,
    col = 1
  ),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = names(df),
  timevar = "grp"
)
```

which gives

```
   id       stday age stday2 col.3 col.1 col.2 col.4
1   1 -0.56047565  14     67     1    NA    NA    NA
2   2 -0.23017749  41      9    NA     1    NA    NA
3   3  1.55870831  41     38    NA    NA     1    NA
4   4  0.07050839  37     27    NA    NA     1    NA
5   5  0.12928774  15     81    NA    NA    NA     1
6   6  1.71506499  14     45    NA    NA     1    NA
7   7  0.46091621  23     81    NA    NA    NA     1
8   8 -1.26506123  47     81    NA    NA    NA     1
9   9 -0.68685285  27     79     1    NA    NA    NA
10 10 -0.44566197  86     44    NA    NA     1    NA
11 11  1.22408180   5     75     1    NA    NA    NA
12 12  0.35981383  44     63     1    NA    NA    NA
13 13  0.40077145  80     71     1    NA    NA    NA
14 14  0.11068272  12      0    NA     1    NA    NA
15 15 -0.55584113  56     48    NA    NA     1    NA
16 16  1.78691314  21     22    NA    NA     1    NA
17 17  0.49785048  13     38    NA    NA     1    NA
18 18 -1.96661716  75     61     1    NA    NA    NA
19 19  0.70135590  90     35    NA    NA     1    NA
20 20 -0.47279141  37     11    NA    NA     1    NA
```